# Initial project build gives error CS 2001 .cshtml.g.cs could not be found

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

.net core 2.2 project was running fine but since some days i am getting errors for .cshtml.g.cs could not be found. So, i tried to create a new project on .net core 2.2 the new projects also gives the same error. My some projects are on dotnet core 2.2 which cannot be updated to 3.1 for some reasons for some time so need a help on this.

Below is the type of error i am getting

> Error CS2001  Source file
>   '/......\obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\Razor\Views\Shared\Error.cshtml.g.cs'
>   could not be found.

Also i tried creating a new controller and view the view also gets into the same type of error. Can some one please help me out on this error.

Comment: Could you have a look at this [link](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/17554#issuecomment-561314410)which may be helpful?

Comment: I did follow the same things mentioned and it got solved but in my case i need to install and uninstall twice since there was some .net core version issues the system was not able to detect any .net core sdks' but now its all fine.